# MVC 3 Razor page encoded as utf 8 shows encoded characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, encoding, razor, utf-8

I have a VirtualPathProvider which takes source code from my DB as a plain string and encodes it as UTF8.

For example:

```
public override Stream Open()
{
  MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();

  result = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_sourceCode));

  return result;
}
```

I then have a layout master page which has its charset as UTF 8

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The master page then calls `@RenderBody()` which gets my VirtualPathProvider page and outputs it to the browser.

The problem is that it is outputting the page with its encoded characters:

> wünschte becomes  wÃ¼nschte

What am I doing wrong?

**TLDR:**

I want wünschte to display instead of wÃ¼nschte. The plain string from the DB is wünschte, but once it comes from the memory stream onto my page it becomes wÃ¼nschte.

Comment: So your problem is you do not want to show UTF 8 encoded strings ?

Comment: By specifying the charset, the encoded string should be rendered as a normal looking string. That is what I understand of it anyway.

Comment: No, you have specified charset to UTF-8, so it would display all non english Characters in there original format.

Comment: How would I then push the bytes into the memory stream without specifying an encoding?

Comment: If you do not specify encoding, the characters would not be rendered. A kind of rectangle box would be displayed instead of character. Do you want to display this rectangle box instead of characters ?

Comment: I want wünschte to display instead of wÃ¼nschte. The plain string from the DB is wünschte, but once it comes from the memory stream it becomes wÃ¼nschte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As someone who struggled with this today with his own `VirtualPathProvider` implementation, it turns out that Razor *really* wants the byte order mark. You can force this by calling `GetPreamble()`.

```
using System.Linq; // for Concat() because I am lazy

public override Stream Open()
{
    var template = Encoding.UTF8
        .GetBytes(this.Template);
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8
        .GetPreamble()
        .Concat(template)
        .ToArray();
    return new MemoryStream(buffer);
}
```

If the BOM isn't there, Razor seems to default to the current codepage and not UTF8. The above fixed it for me.

In the example above, you'd replace `this.Template` in my implementation with `_sourceCode` in the original question.

Comment: I was having the same issue and this solved. Should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: It's also important to save the .cshtml file with UTF BOM. Also for "regular usage", not via Stream.