# Accented characters in Views are not rendered properly

Tags: .net, razor, unicode, servicestack

I'm using [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/) (v3.9.44.0) as a Windows Service (targeting .Net4.5) and I use [Razor](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/View-and-template-selection) to let ServiceStack generate and serve HTML.

Things work pretty well, but there is an odd issue: it seems that hardcoded unicode strings in the view `.cshtml` are not properly rendered.
This is what I mean:

[image: Accents in Views are not rendered properly]

The structure of the project views is canonical:

[image: Views project structure]

With `_Layout.cshtml` being:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Accents in \Views\_Layout.cshtml: à é ë ô</p>

        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

and `Articles.cshtml`:

```
@inherits ViewPage<List<PrepaService.Article>>

<p>Accents in \Views\Articles.cshtml: à é ë ô</p>

Table with code-injected list of items:
<table>
    @foreach(var a in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@a.Description</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Both files are properly saved as BOM-less UTF8 files.

I also tried to add the following, but it doesn't change anything:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    AppendUtf8CharsetOnContentTypes = new HashSet<string> { ContentType.Html }
});
```

#### So, to recap:

- I'm using BOM-less UTF8 encoding for all files and explicit `charset=utf-8` content-type definition.
- this works for anything rendered in `_Layout.cshtml`, and anything injected by code inside the View templates
- but it **doesn't work for hard-coded strings in the View templates**.

#### References:

- [UTF-8 Encoding trouble and no view in snapshot](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/aRZjv2-bzQA/SyIBn6N71PcJ)
- [Beware UTF-8 BOM](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler/issues/3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, answering my own question in case someone stumble on a similar issue:

- Razor seems to require that all files be UTF8 **with** BOM.

I was misled by one of the references apparently but found [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519992/mvc-3-razor-page-encoded-as-utf-8-shows-encoded-characters).

It now works properly.

Comment: On a related note, this is how you add a BOM to all the razor files: ` sed -i '1s/^\(\xef\xbb\xbf\)\?/\xef\xbb\xbf/' *.cshtml`. It handles both files with and without bom.